# how to use pandas drop nan number, not drop all the row

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, nan

I need just delete the `NaN` element, not delete all the rows.

I hava a python dataframe list like :

```
[[2.0, 3.0, 5.0, nan], [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0], [2.0, 5.0, nan, nan]]
```

How can I use pandas to  change it as follow  :  just delete the `NaN` element

```
[[2.0, 3.0, 5.0], [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0], [2.0, 5.0]]
```

Which method can do it better?

Comment: `[[2.0, 3.0, 5.0, nan], [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0], [2.0, 5.0, nan, nan]]` is one column or `DataFrame` ?

Comment: You have not shown any method.

Comment: @ChristophTerasa  i just want to know,which method can do this.

Comment: @jezrael  it is a dataframe

Comment: @liugang - but if it is `DataFrame`, `NaN` are added automatically - `df = pd.DataFrame([[2.0, 3.0, 5.0], [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0], [2.0, 5.0]])`. Then what is desired output? Replace `NaN` to something?

Comment: @jezrael   then i can change it to a list, but "nan" is not my wanted. i  want to delete it

Comment: @liugang You say you have found a method on your own, and ask for a "better" one, but I don't see anything which resembles code. Since `pandas.DataFrame`s need to be rectangular (NxM), missing values will get filled with `NaN` on creation. You either have to deal with the `NaN` values, or not use `pandas.DataFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is problem remove `NaN` from `DataFrame`, very nice it explain [Christoph Terasa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068023/how-to-use-pandas-drop-nan-number-not-drop-all-the-row/38068385#comment63574586_38068023):

> Since pandas.DataFrames need to be rectangular (NxM), missing values will get filled with NaN on creation.

One possible solution is remove it by `list comprehension`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2.0, 3.0, 5.0, np.nan], 
                   [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0], 
                   [2.0, 5.0, np.nan, np.nan]])

print (df)
   0  1     2     3
0  2  3     5   NaN
1  1  3     5     6
2  2  5   NaN   NaN
```

Convert to `list` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and remove `NaN` by condition with [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.isnull.html).

Thank you [Christoph Terasa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38068023/how-to-use-pandas-drop-nan-number-not-drop-all-the-row/38068385#comment63575007_38068385) for this solution:

```
a = [[j for j in i if not pd.isnull(j)] for i in df.values]
print (a)
[[2.0, 3.0, 5.0], [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0], [2.0, 5.0]]
```

My old solution:

You can first replace `NaN` to `None`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2.0, 3.0, 5.0, np.nan], 
                   [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0], 
                   [2.0, 5.0, np.nan, np.nan]])

df = df.where((pd.notnull(df)), None)
print (df)
   0  1     2     3
0  2  3     5  None
1  1  3     5     6
2  2  5  None  None
```

Convert to `list` `L` and then remove `None`:

```
L = [[2.0, 3.0, 5.0, None], [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0], [2.0, 5.0, None, None]]

a = [[i for i in x if i != None] for x in L]

print (a)
[[2.0, 3.0, 5.0], [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0], [2.0, 5.0]]
```

Comment: I think it's a bit unnecessary to fill the `DataFrame` with `None` first. You can directly do the list comprehension on the `DataFrame`: `a = [[j for j in i if not pd.isnull(j)] for i in df.values]`.

Comment: Thank you, I add it to answer.

Comment: Good, you fixed my mistake too. :D

Comment: I think it is was typo ;)

Answer (score 1):

@jezrael is correct.  pandas requires the dataframe to be rectangular.  However, you can change the shape of your rectangle.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[2.0, 3.0, 5.0, np.nan], [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0], [2.0, 5.0, np.nan, np.nan]])

df

     0    1    2    3
0  2.0  3.0  5.0  NaN
1  1.0  3.0  5.0  6.0
2  2.0  5.0  NaN  NaN

df.stack()

0  0    2.0
   1    3.0
   2    5.0
1  0    1.0
   1    3.0
   2    5.0
   3    6.0
2  0    2.0
   1    5.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.replace('NaN', 0)
```

then simply exclude the 0

```
df = df[df[] > 0]
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to print the data frame (df) without "nan" being displayed, you could just replace it with blank by

```
df2=df.fillna("")
```

The resulting dataframe, (df2) will have the same number of rows and columns as original but blanks instead of nan.

Comment: it will be   :[[2.0, 3.0, 5.0, ''], [1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 6.0], [2.0, 5.0, '', '']].  it is not ok